# connecting to Neo4jClient with C#

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

Am very new to the graph databases and need some help to start using Neo4jClient with asp.net using C# ... 
 
I use visual studio 2012 .. I'll be very appreciated if you can provide me with some documentations or articles about this topic . 
 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, learn Neo4j: http://www.neo4j.org/learn/online_course

Then, connect Neo4jClient from your .NET app: https://github.com/readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/connecting

Finally, convert the Cypher queries you learnt about in step 1 to C#: https://github.com/readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples